# Reset the session timeout when the Yes button of the modal popup is clicked

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want the session timeout to reset when the YES button of the Modal Popup  is clicked. At the moment the JavaScript code just hide the Modal pop up. Everything else is working as it should. Thanks

HTLML Code

```
  <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
  </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <h3>Session Idle:&nbsp;<span id="secondsIdle"></span>&nbsp;seconds.   </h3>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFake" runat="server" />
   <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeTimeout" BehaviorID ="mpeTimeout"  runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlPopup" TargetControlID="lnkFake"
      OkControlID="btnYes" CancelControlID="btnNo"  BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" OnOkScript = "ResetSession()">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none">
<div class="header">
    Session Expiring!
</div>
<div class="body">
    Your Session will expire in&nbsp;<span id="seconds"></span>&nbsp;seconds.<br />
    Do you want to reset?
</div>
<div class="footer" align="right">
    <asp:Button ID="btnYes" runat="server" Text="Yes" CssClass="yes" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnNo" runat="server" Text="No" CssClass="no" />
</div>
```

I want the JavaScript code to handle the session reset at the moment the code just hide the modal popup

JavaScript code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function SessionExpireAlert(timeout) {
        var seconds = timeout / 1000;
        document.getElementsByName("secondsIdle").innerHTML = seconds;
        document.getElementsByName("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
        setInterval(function () {
            seconds--;
            document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
            document.getElementById("secondsIdle").innerHTML = seconds;
        }, 1000);
        setTimeout(function () {
            //Show Popup before 20 seconds of timeout.
            $find("mpeTimeout").show();
        }, timeout - 20 * 1000);
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location = "Login.aspx";
        }, timeout);
    };
    function ResetSession() {
        // Hide Modal Popup
        $find('mpeTimeout').hide();

        // Reset Session Here

    }

    </script>
```

C# Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    if (this.IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["Reset"] = true;
        Configuration config =   WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/Web.Config");
       SessionStateSection section = (SessionStateSection)config.GetSection("system.web/sessionState");
       int timeout = (int)section.Timeout.TotalMinutes * 1000 * 60;
       ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SessionAlert", "SessionExpireAlert(" + timeout + ");", true);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Use  jquery/ajax. Why postback?

Comment: @T.S Any code suggestion please

Comment: I give you idea - google is full of these things (code). Create web method in aspx page and call it using one of Ajax wrappers (jquery is one well documented, open source js library).

Answer (score 0):

```
        <script src="/jQuery/Plugins/js.cookie-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                    var popupTimeOut;
                    var fullSessionTimeOut;
                    var timer;
                    var CookiesTime;
                    var localMillisUTC;
                    var counter = 120;
                    var PopUpShown = false;

                    function getCookiesTime() {
                        CookiesTime = Cookies.get('SQSessionTimeOutTime');
                        if (typeof (CookiesTime) == 'undefined') {
                            CookiesTime = 0;
                            clearInterval(timer);
                            clearInterval(popupTimeOut);
                        }
                        return CookiesTime;
                    }

                    function timedCount(timeout) {

                        popupTimeOut = setInterval(function () {
                            localMillisUTC = (new Date()).getTime();//this is UTC since 1970
                            var difference = getCookiesTime() - localMillisUTC;

                            if (difference < 120000) {
                                if (!PopUpShown) {
                                    showPopTimerPopUp();
                                }
                            } else {
                                clearInterval(timer);
                                $find('mpeTimeout').hide();
                                counter = 120;
                            }
                            if (difference <= 0) {
                                SessionTimeOut();
                                clearInterval(timer);
                                $find('mpeTimeout').dispose();
                                clearInterval(popupTimeOut);
                            }
                        }, 10000);
                    }
                    function startSessionCount(timeout) {
                        if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
                            timedCount(timeout);
                        }
                    }   

                    function showPopTimerPopUp()
                    {
                        PopUpShown = true;
                        $find('mpeTimeout').show();                            
                        timer = setInterval(function () {
                            localMillisUTC = (new Date()).getTime();//this is UTC since 1970
                            var countDownTimer = (getCookiesTime() - localMillisUTC);
                            var counter = parseInt(((getCookiesTime() - localMillisUTC) / 1000));
                            if (countDownTimer <= 0) {
                                SessionTimeOut();
                                clearInterval(timer);
                                $("#seconds").html(counter);
                            }
                            else if (countDownTimer > 120000)
                            {
                                PopUpShown = false;
                                $find('mpeTimeout').hide();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $("#seconds").html(counter);
                            }
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                    function resetSession() {
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        keepServerSideSessionAliveAjax();
                        PopUpShown = false;
                    }
                    function SessionTimeOut() {
                         var urlPath = $(location).attr('pathname');
                         var erroMessage= '<%=GetTranslation("msg=Your session timed out, please login below", "lsessionTimeoutmsg")%>';
                         window.location = encodeURI("../SessionEnd.aspx?RedirectUrl=" + urlPath + "&" + erroMessage);
                    }
                    function noSessionExp() {
                        clearInterval(popupTimeOut);
                    }
                    function keepServerSideSessionAliveAjax() {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/Main/SessionAliveKeeper.aspx/GetSessionTimer",
                            data: "{}",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (result) {
                            }
                        });
                    }
        </script>


<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeTimeout" runat="server" BehaviorID="mpeTimeout" TargetControlID="lnkFake" PopupControlID="pnlPopup" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" OkControlID="btnYes" CancelControlID="btnNo" OnOkScript="resetSession();" OnCancelScript="noSessionExp()" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFake" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none" SkinID="modal">
                        <div class="frame">
                            <div class="Popupcontainer" style="width: 220px">
                                <div id="popupDaysHeader" class="header" style="cursor: move">
                                    <div class="msg">
                                        <%= GetTranslation("Session Expiring!","lheaderSessionExp")%>
                                    </div>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" CssClass="close" OnClientClick="$find('mpeTimeout').hide(); return false;" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="Popupbody">
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                     <%= GetTranslation("Your Session will expire in","ltxtSessionExp1") %>&nbsp;<span id="seconds"></span>&nbsp;seconds.<br />
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                     <%=GetTranslation("Do you want to reset?","ltxtTransaltionExp3") %><br />
                                    <br />
                                    <span style="align-items:right;">
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnYes" runat="server" Text="Yes" CssClass="yes" />
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnNo" runat="server" Text="No" CssClass="no" OnClientClick="SessionTimeOut()"/>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div style="text-align: right">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
```

This is whole ascx page and whenever user clicks yes server timeout will reset you just need to update cookie. This is modification to you code

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/SessionTimeoutPopup/SessionTimeoutPopup.ascx" TagName="SessionTimeoutPopup" TagPrefix="st" %>
```

You can add this line to any page and it will work ..there are certain thing missing but i guess you will figure it out  if you need more help let me know..

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Look like GetTranslation is missing. I am getting the error "The name 'GetTranslation' does not exist in the current context" any help how to solve it.

Comment: just remove that function, we use that for translation.  @EricMbiada and if you think ans is helpfull please vote for it

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can use these Script on your Master Page or other ,

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

     var sess_pollInterval = 60000;
     var sess_expirationMinutes = 20;
     var sess_warningMinutes = 15;
     var sess_intervalID;
     var sess_lastActivity;

     function initSession() {
         sess_lastActivity = new Date();
         sessSetInterval();
         $(document).bind('keypress.session', function (ed, e) {
             sessKeyPressed(ed, e);
         });
     }

     function sessSetInterval() {
         sess_intervalID = setInterval('sessInterval()', sess_pollInterval);
     }

     function sessClearInterval() {
         clearInterval(sess_intervalID);
     }

     function sessKeyPressed(ed, e) {
         sess_lastActivity = new Date();
     }

     function sessLogOut() {
         window.location.href = 'Default.aspx';
     }

     function sessInterval() {
         var now = new Date();
         //get milliseconds of differneces 
         var diff = now - sess_lastActivity;
         //get minutes between differences
         var diffMins = (diff / 1000 / 60);

         if (diffMins >= sess_warningMinutes) {
             //wran before expiring
             //stop the timer
             sessClearInterval();
             //promt for attention
             var active = confirm('Your session will expire in ' + (sess_expirationMinutes - sess_warningMinutes) +
                 ' minutes (as of ' + now.toTimeString() + '), press OK to remain logged in ' +
                 'or press Cancel to log off.');
             if (active == true) {
                 now = new Date();
                 diff = now - sess_lastActivity;
                 diffMins = (diff / 1000 / 60);

                 if (diffMins > sess_expirationMinutes) {
                     sessLogOut();
                 }
                 else {
                     initSession();
                     sessSetInterval();
                     sess_lastActivity = new Date();
                 }
             }
             else {
                 sessLogOut();
             }
         }
     }
    </script>
```